# Find a line in a file and replace the next line

Tags: windows, batch-file, replace

Using a .bat script, I want to find a line that says `# Site 1` and replace the text in the next line with a variable. I found tutorials on StackOverflow for finding and replacing a line, but not finding a line and replacing the next line. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off

set "the_file=C:\someFile"
set "search_for=somestring"
set "variable=http://site1"

for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%# in ('findstr /n  /c:"%search_for%" "%the_file%"') do (
    set "line=%%#"
    goto :break
)
:break


set /a lineBefore=line-1
set /a nextLine=line+1


break>"%temp%\empty"&&fc "%temp%\empty" "%the_file%" /lb  %lineBefore% /t |more +4 | findstr /B /E /V "*****" >newFile
echo %variable%>>newFile
more "%the_file%" +%nextLine% 1>>newFile

echo move /y newFile "%the_file%"
```

Check if `newFile` is ok and remove the `echo` at the front of the last line.

you need to set the three variables at the beginning by yourself.Have on mind that more command sets spaces instead of tabs

Comment: So what exactly does each variable mean?

Comment: @AidanEdwards - the variable you want to set on the next line (after search_for)

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working with this:
set /p ip="Insert server ip:"

set "the_file=pc2v9.ini"
set "search_for=# Site 1"
set "variable=server="%ip%":50002"

Comment: @AidanEdwards have you checked the content of `newFile` ? It should be in the same directory as the script.

Comment: it is, how do I make it automatically replace?

Comment: @AidanEdwards - if the `newFile` is ok remove (only) `echo`  from the last line.

Comment: Awesome! This does exactly what I want it to, then! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "filename=q28567045.txt"
SET "afterme=# Site 1"
SET "putme=put this line after # Site 1"
SET "skip1="
(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename%") DO (
 IF DEFINED skip1 (ECHO(%putme%) ELSE (ECHO(%%a)
 SET "skip1="
 IF /i "%%a"=="%afterme%" SET skip1=y
)
)>newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF
```

Produces newfile.txt

The flag `skip1 to skip the line is first reset, then the file is read line by line.

If the `skip1` flag is set, then the replacement line is `echo`ed in place of the line read; if not, the line read is echoed.

Then the `skip1` flag is cleared

If the line read to `%%a` matches the string assigned to `afterme` then the flag `skip1` is set (to `y` - but it doesn't matter what the value is)

Note that empty lines and those starting `;` will be ignored and not reproduced - this is standard behaviour of `for /f`.

If you want to replce the starting file, then simply add

```
move /y newfile.txt "%filename%"
```

before the `goto :eof` line.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I enjoy working with batch, I generally avoid using pure native batch to edit text files because a robust solution is usually complicated and slow.

This can be done easily and efficiently using [JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) - a hybrid JScript/batch utility that performs regular expression replacement. JREPL.BAT is pure script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "newVal=Replacement value"
call jrepl "^.*" "%newValue%" /jbeg "skip=true" /jendln "skip=($txt!='# Site 1')" /f test.txt /o -
```

The /F option specifies the file to process

The /O option with value of `-` specifies to replace the original file with the result.

The /JBEG option initializes the command to skip (not replace) each line.

The /JENDLN option checks the value of each line just before it is written out, and sets SKIP off (false) if it matches `# Site 1`. The next line will be replaced only when SKIP is false.

The search string matches an entire line.

The replacement string is your value stored in a variable.