# Using FART to remove an entire line (and replace it with a new one)

Tags: batch-file, replace, dos

I need to remove the following line:

```
user_pref("network.proxy.http", "177.22.10.226");
```

located in the file:

```
%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\zizwksvf.default\prefs.js
```

and replace it with the following line:

```
user_pref("network.proxy.http", "177.22.10.116");
```

i.e. basically I have to replace the address of the proxy using command lines within batch files. 
Since I dont know beforehand which is the line I have to replace(can be any IP) I wanna use * to replace all lines having the string "network.proxy.http" including quotes like this:

```
fart %APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\zizwksvf.default\prefs.js """*network.proxy.http*""" "user_pref("network.proxy.http", "177.22.10.116");"
```

but it does not work, no elemnts are found, while if I try have a previow of how many elements would be sostitute by using:

```
fart -p %APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\zizwksvf.default\prefs.js """network.proxy.http"""
```

it says it finds one element. Any suggestion?

Cheers
A.

Comment: The title* made me lol

Comment: @FirebladeDan That's because you yet have to experience the powers of the [Find And Replace Tool](http://fart-it.sourceforge.net/). :)

Comment: As for the problem. You say with `-p` it finds a match, but that line is different from the other. `"""network.proxy.http"""` vs `"""*network.proxy.http*"""` (asterisks). So probably there in lies the problem?

Comment: Is it just me, or do the lines you want to find and replace look identical?

Comment: Ok i just changed the IP, it is clear I have to change the IP every time. The asterisks should match any letter in the front and in the back if regex works.

Answer (score 4):

Would recommend you to not use anything  hosted on [sourceforge](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/05/sourceforge-grabs-gimp-for-windows-account-wraps-installer-in-bundle-pushing-adware/) .
You can do that without any pre-compiled binaries.
You can try [replacer.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/replacer.bat)  (the `e?` before the file name is for evaluation of unicode sequences - quotes in this case )

```
call replacer.bat "e?%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\zizwksvf.default\prefs.js" "user_pref(\u0022network.proxy.http\u0022, \u0022177.22.10.116\u0022);" "user_pref(\u0022network.proxy.http\u0022, \u0022177.22.10.116\u0022);"
```

you can check also [FindRepl](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4697) and [JRepl](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) which are more sophisticated tools

**EDIT**.According to the help [page](http://fart-it.sourceforge.net/) you can use `-C` option and use `\x22` instead of double quotes in your arguments.

Comment: Thanks, but I already downloaded FART and its pretty nice, I would just like to know how to that with FART.

Comment: @Alberto escape the quotes with the `-C` option

Answer (score 1):

There are several different ways to do that with Batch files, from the advanced tools that npocmaka suggested to simpler one-purpose Batch files; like this one:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "find=network.proxy.http"
set "repl=user_pref("network.proxy.http", "177.22.10.116");"

rem Get the line number of the search line
for /F "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N /C:"%find%" input.txt') do set /A "numLines=%%a-1"

rem Open a code block to read-input-file/create-output-file

< input.txt (

   rem Copy numLines-1 lines
   set /P line=
   for /L %%i in (1,1,%numLines%) do (
      echo(!line!
      set "line="
      set /P "line="
   )

   rem Replace the search line
   echo %repl%

   rem Copy the rest of lines
   findstr "^"

) > output.txt

rem Replace input file with created output file
move /Y output.txt input.txt > NUL
```

This Batch file is a modification of the one posted at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28567045/find-a-line-in-a-file-and-replace-the-next-line/28569440#28569440).

Comment: fart HUGEFILE.sql "\"" "" --remove, this remove in 3GB size fgile in seconds