# Find slightly variable string and replace following line with contents of a text file

Tags: batch-file, find-replace

I'm trying to automate a slightly laborious process which is involved in running computational chemistry calculations with a couple of free pieces of software. I've managed to find answers to most of what I need to do, but I'm missing the last piece of the puzzle, probably because it's quite unusual, and I don't know if it's possible with my chosen language - batch files. I chose this partly because I've had difficulty in the past getting C++ or JavaScript to read or edit other files, and Batch (which was recommended by a friend) did this first time without any difficulty.

I've copied a representative sample of  my input file below.

```
Text above

 $DATA  
Adenosine                                                                
C1     0
O           8.0      0.1319600000      7.8748100000      0.9316500000
    DZV     0

C           6.0     -0.5337400000      7.9322600000      2.1608300000
   DZV     0

N           7.0      1.4158500000      4.2659800000      1.3661200000
   DZV     0

H           1.0     -0.4456400000      8.9556600000      2.5897400000
   DZV     0

More coordinates below
```

I would like to be able to (for example) find the string `O           8.0`, and replace the contents of the next line with the contents of a text file. The format,

```
Atom           atomic charge            coordinates
   text
blank space
```

needs to remain - the blank space is essential.

An example of the end product is here (for oxygen and carbon; nitrogen and hydrogen have been omitted for brevity):

```
 $DATA  
Adenosine                                                                       
C1       0
O           8.0      0.1319600000      7.8748100000      0.9316500000
S   5
1      2266.1767785             -0.53431809926E-02
2       340.87010191            -0.39890039230E-01
3        77.363135167           -0.17853911985
4        21.479644940           -0.46427684959
5         6.6589433124          -0.44309745172
S   1
1         0.80975975668          1.0000000
S   1
1         0.25530772234          1.0000000
P   3
1        17.721504317            0.43394573193E-01
2         3.8635505440           0.23094120765
3         1.0480920883           0.51375311064
P   1
1         0.27641544411          1.0000000
D   1
1         1.2000000              1.0000000

C           6.0     -0.5337400000      7.9322600000      2.1608300000
S   5
1      1238.4016938              0.54568832082E-02
2       186.29004992             0.40638409211E-01
3        42.251176346            0.18025593888
4        11.676557932            0.46315121755
5         3.5930506482           0.44087173314
S   1
1         0.40245147363          1.0000000
S   1
1         0.13090182668          1.0000000
P   3
1         9.4680970621           0.38387871728E-01
2         2.0103545142           0.21117025112
3         0.54771004707          0.51328172114
P   1
1         0.15268613795          1.0000000
D   1
1         0.8000000              1.0000000
```

I've managed to successfully do find and replace for strings using the following code:

```
set "search=SearchItem"
set "replace=Replacement"
set "textfile=text.txt"
set "newfile=newfile.txt"
(for /f "delims=" %%i in (%textfile%) do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
    echo(!line!
    endlocal
))>"%newfile%"
del %textfile%
rename %newfile%  %textfile%
```

I've found "Find a line in a file and replace the next line"-type code here: [Find a line in a file and replace the next line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28567045/find-a-line-in-a-file-and-replace-the-next-line)
But this doesn't quite work - the code seems to turn:

```
Atom           atomic charge            coordinates
   text
blank space
```

into:

```
blank space
replacement text
blank space
```

And it only does this for one atom.

Comment: Where is all the information for the replacements from? I mean, how to you specify what atom information needs to replaced by what? please [edit] your question and include such details there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q57608034.txt"
SET "filename2=%sourcedir%\q57608034_repl.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"

SET "col1=O"
SET "col2=8.0"

SET "replacenext="

(
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=[]" %%s IN ('find /n /v "" "%filename1%"') DO (
 IF DEFINED replacenext (SET "replacenext="&TYPE "%filename2%
 ) ELSE (
  FOR /f "tokens=1,2" %%c IN ("%%t") DO IF "%%c"=="%col1%" IF "%%d"=="%col2%" SET "replacenext=Y"
  ECHO(%%t
 )
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances. The listing uses a setting that suits my system.

I used a file named `q57608034.txt` containing your data for my testing.

I used a file named `q57608034_repl.txt` containing some dummy replacement data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as `%outfile%`

I'm working solely with your statement **I would like to be able to (for example) find the string O           8.0, and replace the contents of the next line with the contents of a text file. The format,**

Sadly, you've described the result, but not provided an example.

The code above will find the two target strings, then replace the following line with the contents of a file.

The outer loop uses as input the output of `find...` which prefixes each line with a line number in [brackets]. No line of the file will match `""` since `""` will not match *any* lines in the file (including empty lines). The `/v` reverses the condition, showing lines that do *not* match `""` which is *every line*. the `/n` then prefixes each line with `[number]`.

The resultant "input" is then tokenised using `[]` as delimiters and selecting tokens `1` to be assigned to `%%s` and `*` (which means the remainder of the line - the whole actual line read from the source file) to `%%t`.

Since `replacenext` is initialised to *nothing* (ie it becomes `not defined`) then the `else` part of the `if` statement is executed. This tokenises "%%t" - the literal string from the file and selects the first two columns (using the default delimiters <kbd>Space</kbd> <kbd>,</kbd> and <kbd>;</kbd> into `%%c` and `%%d`. If these two values match those specified as variables `col1` and `col2` then `replacenext` is set to a value. `%%t` is then `echo`ed, regurgitating the line read from the original file.

When the next line is read, `replacenext` may now be defined and if it is, the replacementt text is copied in from the replacement-text file, then `replacenext` is cleared and so the following lines will be interpreted again for matching `col1` and `col2`.

The result of which is:

```
Text above

$DATA
Adenosine
C1     0
O           8.0      0.1319600000      7.8748100000      0.9316500000
Replacement Text

C           6.0     -0.5337400000      7.9322600000      2.1608300000
DZV     0

N           7.0      1.4158500000      4.2659800000      1.3661200000
DZV     0

H           1.0     -0.4456400000      8.9556600000      2.5897400000
DZV     0

More coordinates below
```

Comment: Your response is far more detailed than I expected, thank you! Despite my omitting a possibly crucial example, the code works perfectly. however, for some reason when I change out the relevant words in the code for the carbon `C           6.0` or nitrogen `N           7.0` lines, nothing is altered.

Comment: Worked fine for me. Try replacing the `for...%%c...` line with ` FOR /f "tokens=1,2" %%c IN ("%%t") DO >con ECHO 1 "%%c" "%col1%"&IF "%%c"=="%col1%" >con ECHO 2 "%%d" "%col2%"&IF "%%d"=="%col2%" >con ECHO 3 setting&SET "replacenext=Y"`  (all one physical line) The `>con` redirects the following `echo` to the console rather than the file, the `&` logically concatenates commands. You should see the comparison stage-by-stage. I'd suggest that you use a censored data file like the literal example you've provided, else the console report may be overwhelming.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I had forgotten to change `SET "col1=O"` to `SET "col1=C"`, which meant the computer couldn't find a line with `O     6.0`. Hence, since computers do exactly what you tell them to, nothing was changed. The expanded `for...%%c...` line enabled me to twig what was going on.

Answer (score 0):

[Magoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2128947/magoo)s good answer uses the usual techniques with find for numbering and
a flag variable which avoids delayedexpansion.

To detect the trigger lines you might also echo to findstr with it's RegEx capabilities or
just compare the begin of the line exactly:

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\08\22\SO_57608034.cmd
@Echo off
set "search=O           8"
set "textfile=text.txt"
set "newfile=newfile.txt"
set "insertfile=other.txt"
Set "SkipNextLine="

(for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%h in ('find /N /V "" "%textfile%") do (
    if defined SkipNextLine (
       type "%insertfile%"
       Set "SkipNextLine="
    ) else (
        Echo:%%i|findstr /BC:"%search%" >NUL 2>&1 && Set SkipNextLine=yes
        Echo:%%i
    )
))>"%newfile%"
del "%textfile%"
rename "%newfile%"  "%textfile%"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty incomplete:

- Do you want to perform *several* replacements? If so,
- How do you specify the required replacements?
- Why do you need to replace with *a text file*? Isn't enough a string?

I used my own ideas to resolve your missing requirements:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define the replacement set
set i=0
for %%a in (
      "O           8.0= Replace   X"
      "N           7.0=   Other   Y"
      "EndOfSet" ) do (
   set /A i+=1
   set "replace[!i!]=%%~a"
)

rem Initialize the replacement set
set /A i=1, repLen=15, repThis=0
set "search=%replace[1]%"

rem Process the file
(for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" test.txt') do (
   if !repThis! equ 1 (
      for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%x in ("!search!") do echo %%x
      set /A i+=1, repThis=0
      for %%i in (!i!) do set "search=!replace[%%i]!"
   ) else (
      echo/%%b
      set "line=%%b"
      if "!line:~0,%repLen%!" == "!search:~0,%repLen%!" set "repThis=1"
   )
)) > newFile.txt
```

Output:

Text above

```
 $DATA  
Adenosine                                                                
C1     0
O           8.0      0.1319600000      7.8748100000      0.9316500000
 Replace   X

C           6.0     -0.5337400000      7.9322600000      2.1608300000
   DZV     0

N           7.0      1.4158500000      4.2659800000      1.3661200000
   Other   Y

H           1.0     -0.4456400000      8.9556600000      2.5897400000
   DZV     0

More coordinates below
```

Please note that the replacement set must be defined *in the same order* of the data file...